# Output format is wrong

Tags: c++

i submitted this on codeforces 
the checker's comment came-'"wrong output format Expected integer, but "Enter" found""
where is the mistake

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main(){
     int n,m,a,i,l = 0,k = 0;

     cout<<"Enter the values of n,m,a";
     cin>>n;
     cout<<"\n";
     cin>>m;
     cout<<"\n";
     cin>>a;

     for(i = a ; i < n ; i = i + a){
         l++;
     }

     for(i = a ; i < m ; i = i + a){
         k++;
     }

     cout<<"The least number of flagstones needed is"<<(l+1)*(k+1);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you supposed to output anything except the actual result?

Comment: Are the `for` loops required?  Looks like you could reduce them to one math expression each.

Answer (score 6):

On competition websites you should not print anything but the expected answer thus all the messages like `"Enter the values of n,m,a"` and the newlines should not be there. Remove all `cout`-s and leave only the last one like `cout<<(l+1)*(k+1)<<endl;` codeforces does not care too much but usually you should have an empty line after your last output line.